# Variable undeclared even if it was in C program

Tags: c, struct, error-handling, compiler-errors, structure

There is an error that says that `book` is undeclared and a note that says "each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in". But I don't understand why it only applies to `book.title` yet other members in the `struct` remain unaffected.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct LIS
{
  char title[75];
  char author[75];
  char borrower_name[75];
  int days_borrowed;
  float fine;
};

struct book;

void main() {

  int response;

  do {
    printf("Title of the book: ");
    gets(book.title);
    printf("Author(s) of the book: ");
    gets(book.author);
    printf("Name of borrower: ");
    gets(book.borrower_name);
    printf("Number of days borrowed: ");
    scanf("%d", &book.days_borrowed);
    if(book.days_borrowed > 3) { book.fine = 5.00 * (book.days_borrowed-3); }
    else { book.fine = 0; }

    printf("Fine (if applicable): %.2f\n", book.fine);

    printf("Enter any key continue/Enter 0 to end: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &response);
  } while (response != 0);

}
```

Comment: `struct book;` is incomplete. Did you mean something like `struct LIS
{/* ... */
}  book;`? That is, did you try to remove the `; struct` before `book`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace the code for `book` definition like this:

```
struct LIS
{
char title[75];
char author[75];
char borrower_name[75];
int days_borrowed;
float fine;
} book;
```

or like this:

```
struct LIS
{
char title[75];
char author[75];
char borrower_name[75];
int days_borrowed;
float fine;
}; 
struct LIS book;
```

The variable `book` needs a structure type definition. Simply writing `struct book;` will not specify what kind of structure `book` is.

---

Also, note that the function `gets` was removed from the C Standard, since it is not safe. Instead, you should use something like this:

```
fgets(book.title,sizeof(book.title),stdin);
```

Comment: Thanks! I have done this and there are no compiler errors now.